# how to get data from array with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I can put data in to array, But i can't get data from array.
I give you my code

```
<span id="test"></span>


<script>
$(function() 
{
    var c = 1;
    var i = 5;
      var data = [[]];

      for ( c = 1 ; c <= i ; c++ )
      {
         data[c] = [];
         data[c]['proDetails'] = 'asdasf';
         data[c]['proDeCount'] = 'qweqwrqwr';
      }
      c=1;
      alert(data);
      $('#test').html(data);


      $.each(data,function(key, val) 
        {
            $('#test').html(
                  $('#test').html()
                        +$('#test').html(val['proDetails'])
                        +$('#test').html(val['proDeCount'])
            );
        });
})
</script>
```

Ps.Sorry My English is mot well.

WTF i don't have not thing to say why this page tell me "it is more code please insert some text"

Comment: It's unclear to me what result you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way you put it in.

```
for ( c = 1 ; c <= i ; c++ )
{
    $('#test').text($('#test').text() + " " + data[c]['proDetails'] + " " + data[c]['proDeCount']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your .each() statement like this:

```
  $.each(data,function(key) 
        $('#test').html(
              $('#test').html()
                    +$('#test').html(data[key]['proDetails'])
                    +$('#test').html(data[key]['proDeCount'])
        );
    });
```